# Matching exponents using Cases[]

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a question regarding pattern matching. Can anyone explain the results i get ?

```
Cases[Table[x^n, {n, 1, 10}], a_^1]
```

Which gives the following result.

{x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^7, x^8, x^9, x^10}

I was expecting it to return x only similar to the case of x^2 shown below

```
Cases[Table[x^n, {n, 1, 10}], a_^2]
```

{x^2}

Thanks
David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a_^1` is converted to `a_` before `Cases` is executed, matching each element of the `Table`.

```
Trace[Cases[Table[x^n, {n, 1, 10}], a_^1]]
```

(The output is a bit long to be presented here.)

Answer (score 0):

Most Likely is because x^n^1 == x^n

```
x^n == (x^n)^1
(*True*)
```

a_ can be anything including x^n

If you try for example

```
Cases[Table[x^n, {n, 1, 10}], Power[x,1]] 
(*{x}*)
```